# Submit xml to GSA with PHP / foreach loop

Tags: php, search, curl, google-search-appliance

Trying to submit to GSA (google search applicance). Works fine for 1 xml file. But im trying to loop through all files in a directory and submit to the gsa with a loop but cannot get it working.

```
<?php

$target_url = 'http://1.1.1.1:19900/xmlfeed';

$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');

$directory = 'xml';

if (! is_dir($directory)) {
    exit('Invalid diretory path');
}

$files = array();

foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
    if ('.' === $file) continue;
    if ('..' === $file) continue;

}

//print $file;



$fields = array(
'feedtype'=>'incremental',
'datasource'=>'testing',
'data'=>file_get_contents(realpath($file))
//'data'=>file_get_contents(realpath('test.xml')) //works fine

);



$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$return = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $msg = curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);



echo $return;
```

?>

Tried adding a foreach loop but that gives me an error that the file is empty.

Comment: You can delete it yourself.

Comment: If this might in any way be useful to anyone else, the best option would be to supply an answer yourself. If people find it useful, it may garner upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a request for each file. Put your curl execution in the foreach loop and it should be fine :

```
<?php

$target_url = 'http://1.1.1.1:19900/xmlfeed';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$directory = 'xml';

if (! is_dir($directory)) {
    exit('Invalid diretory path');
}

$files = array();

//List all files in the directory
foreach(glob($directory."/*.*") as $file) {

  //Check the file extension
  $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if($ext != 'xml') continue;

  //Add the fields
  $fields = array(
    'feedtype'=>'incremental',
    'datasource'=>'testing',
    'data'=>file_get_contents($file)
  );

  //Post the request
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

  $return = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $msg = curl_error($ch);
  }

  curl_close ($ch);

  //Print the result for each file
  echo "Result for " . basename($file) . " is : " . $return;
}
?>
```

It works fine for me. I hope it will help :)